# error installing flask_swagger_ui on ubuntu server

Tags: python, flask

so im trying to do a pip3 install flask-swagger-ui but im getting the following error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting flask-swagger-ui
  Using cached flask-swagger-ui-3.25.0.tar.gz (521 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-n64v6bxi/flask-swagger-ui/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-n64v6bxi/flask-swagger-ui/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-n64v6bxi/flask-swagger-ui/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-n64v6bxi/flask-swagger-ui/
    Complete output (3 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

please help